# Recognize basic shapes in binarized image using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, shapes, image-recognition

How can I recognize some basic (usually rotated) shapes:

- circle,
- "empty" circle,
- cross,
- empty triangle,

using `OpenCV`? What's the most straightforward way? It would be nice if the user could "define" his own shapes somehow (load a template image, possibly).

I'd like to map each recognized shape to its type (circle, triangle etc.) and a position of its center. (And its rotation if possible).

For circles `HoughCircles` could be used (there's no rotation in this case, too). But what about the others? Template matching doesn't support rotation and scaling, right?...

Here's the input:

[image: empty triangle, empty circle, circles]

[image: empty triangle, empty circle, cross]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that regular template matching are not rotation, scale invariant. Take a look at OpenCV's [`matchShapes`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#matchshapes). Internally, it uses `HuMoments`. You will need to use [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#findcontours) to find each individual object. Now once you have done this, you will probably find `matchShapes` couldn't distinguish Circle from Ring. A simple way to solve this is to use the hierarchy structure from `findContours`. If there is a hole (large enough) inside a Circle, that's probably a Ring.

Comment: Thank you! :) Will do exactly that.